# Setting parameters on the root route in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a shared blog using the Rails 5.0.0.beta2. I'd like to have the `root` route for unprivileged users resolve to `users/:user_id/posts`, which will display all of users posts. As things are currently configured the route is defined as:

`root to: 'posts#index'`

Which returns all of the posts (for all users).

I tried:

`root 'users/:user_id/posts' => 'posts#index', controller: 'posts', action: 'index'`

Which results in:

`root_path GET / posts#index {"users/:user_id/posts"=>"posts#index"}`

At `rails/info/routes` (or `rails routes`). But which doesn't seem to be using the `:user_id` component of the route – all of the published posts are shown. As far as I can tell, there is no route that should do that… (both from inspecting the route table and also from manually entering the route).

I also tried:

`get 'users/:user_id/posts' => 'posts#index', :as => :root`

Which results in:

`root_path GET /users/:user_id/posts(.:format) posts#index`

But the actual page that is served is the "Yay, you're on Rails!" page.

Is it possible to do this? How would I go about it?

Comment: You would have to do a redirect. But why not just display that on the index page for those users?

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what you mean by "display that on the index page for those users."

Comment: Display two different things on the page depending on the type of user.

Comment: Oh, do the branching in the view rather than in the router? No good reason, other than thinking it ought to be possible (and having the code working if I could just get the routes right…).

Comment: Clarify something for me: You want all posts for `unprivileged`(unauthenticated) users.... but only some posts for `privileged` (authenticated) ones?

Comment: All users are authenticated. When a user logs in (or goes "home") I'd like to display their posts (`users/:user_id/posts`). I'd also like it to be possible to display all posts at `users/posts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All users are authenticated

So what you're asking is how to scope the "homepage" `@posts` to those of the `current_user`.

There are two ways to do it (`Controller` and `Devise`):

---

**Controller**

```
#config/routes.rb
root "posts#index" #-> url.com

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @posts = user_signed_in? ? current_user.posts : Post.all
  end
end

#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

This is the simplest way to pull it off.

The routes don't matter -- if your user is signed in, you can scope the data around their `current_user` object.

In both cases, you wish to access `url.com`, so you'd match this with routing that to the `posts#index`. The `@posts` variable can then be scoped to whichever setup works best for you.

---

**Devise**

```
#config/routes.rb
authenticate :user do
  root "posts#user", as: :authenticated_root #-> url.com
end

unauthenticated :user do
  root 'posts#index', as: :root #-> url.com
end
```

Devise has the [`authenticated` && `unauthenticated` route helpers](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper%3Aauthenticated) to give you different sets of routes, depending on whether the user is logged in.

There are 3 helpers in total:

> - `authenticate`    - if user is logged in
> - `authenticated`   - *only* if the user is logged in (hidden other times)
> - `unauthenticated` - if user is not logged in

You could use the above to access the following:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def user
    @posts = current_user.posts
    render :index
  end
end
```

This is not much different than the above method; the reason you'd use it is if you had a marked difference in the flow. IE you set data in `posts#index` which was completely different to `posts#user`.

In my example, both methods use `index.html.erb`; you could easily split them...

```
#app/views/posts/index.html.erb
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ....
<% end %>
```